# SSO between apps on Android

Tags: android, model, single-sign-on

Is there a standard or proven model to authenticate in an sso manner various apps on the same device?
Suppose we have two apps on device that require same login/password credentials to authenticate to the same system.
We want to be able to:
- launch app1
- log in into app1
- launch app2. In the app2, user is already authenticated.

We think to a "pop" model where the first app that does the login, shares authentication's info (e.g. a token). The second app, gets (pop) the token to do sso.

Is there some side effects on this model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider using intents, with only one of the app responsible for authentication. Others will invoke the application responsible for authentication and sso.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html#intents_overview

Your suggested method is similar to the one used by facebook sdk for android for sso, read here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#enablesso

And if facebook is using it, should be field tested and proven.